# Multiplying @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gheimatkol) value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp mvc website that displays content from model from database,i want to change modelitem.

It should be multiplicaton to(*10000000000) and the result shows in a textbox.

What I have tried:

```
<input type="text" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gheimatkol) * 100000000000" readonly/>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: i return =>1/2 * 100000000000 in the textbox, but i want the result of it.

Comment: @sepid Do you need the multiplication in any input field or just displaying?

Comment: i want it will be in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows:

```
<span>@(item.gheimatkol * 100000000000)</span>
```

If you want this in the input field then as follows:

```
<input type="text"  value="@(item.gheimatkol * 100000000000)"  readonly />
```

Comment: i want it will be in the input